# Testing instance methods in Python using mock

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class similarly structured to this:

```
class TestClass:
    def a(self):
        pass

    def b(self):
        self.a()
```

I want to test if running `TestClass().b()` successfully calls `TestClass().a()`:

```
class TestTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_b(self):
        with patch('test_file.TestClass') as mock:
            instance = mock.return_value
            TestClass().b()
            instance.a.assert_called()
```

However, it fails because `a` isn't called. What am I doing wrong? I went through the mock documentation and various other guides to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: You mock the whole class, so everything called for that class will just return a mock and not call the real method (like b in your case). You have to mock specifically `a` instead (e.g. `patch("test_file.TestClass.a")`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [patch.object()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object) to patch the `a()` method of `TestClass`.

E.g.

`test_file.py`:

```py
class TestClass:
    def a(self):
        pass

    def b(self):
        self.a()
```

`test_test_file.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from test_file import TestClass


class TestTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_b(self):
        with patch.object(TestClass, 'a') as mock_a:
            instance = TestClass()
            instance.b()
            instance.a.assert_called()
            mock_a.assert_called()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result:

```
 ⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66707071/test_test_file.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66707071/test_file.py            5      1    80%   3
src/stackoverflow/66707071/test_test_file.py      12      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                             17      1    94%
```